# C# Make protected variable private in a subclass (or other way around the issue)

Tags: c#, inheritance

I do not think this is possible to do, but I am curious.  Is it possible to make a protected variable in a super class private in its subclass.

For example, I have three classes `SuperClass`, `SubClass : SuperClass` and `SubCLass2 : SubClass`.

I want to be able to access variable `protected string[] commands` that is in `SuperClass` from `SubClass` but prevent access to it from `SubClass2`.

If this is not possible, is there anyway to achieve the same effect?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I do not think this is possible to do, but I am curious. Is it possible to make a protected variable in a super class private in its subclass.

No. Personally, I would avoid having the variable non-private in the first place - I'd provide a protected *property*. You *could* create a new property to "hide" the base property... but this smacks of poor design to me.

I can't *think* of any way of getting around the hiding from the grand-child's point of view, without changing one of the other classes, but it feels pretty arbitrary to me:

```
public class Base
{
    private int foo = 5;
    protected int Foo { get { return foo; } }
}

public class Child : Base
{
    protected new int Foo { get { return 0; } }
}

public class GrandChild : Child
{
    // Aargh, can't get at the original Foo...
}
```

Why do you want to achieve this? Perhaps you should seal your direct subclass, and force other classes to use composition instead...

EDIT: As explained in the comments, it sounds like this is a situation where making the property (and I would still make it a property returning a private field) *internal* would be appropriate. That gives access to the property to all other code in the same assembly, but no other assemblies.

Comment: I am doing this mainly because I am writing a small plugin based framework.  I want to my Plugin class (that all user defined plugins inherit) to be able to access properties from the Base Class, but I do not want user defined plugins to be able to change their values.  I can probably just pull getters and setters into the base class, but then they would still be accessible to the grandchild.  I can also just say, if the plugin developer changes the values and the system crashes then thats a problem with the plugin.  But I would like to put safeguards in if possible.

Comment: @RyanSullivan: Why not make the property internal? Then the subclass will have access to it (assuming it's in the same assembly) but the other plugins won't.

Comment: That is perfect, thank you.  I did not even know `internal` existed, I do not normally work in C#  If you can repost that as a "Solution" I will select it as the answer.

Comment: Hiding a protected member from subclasses is IMHO something which should be done more often.  Consider, for example, `MemberwiseClone`.  There's no way any class derived from `List<T>` can *possibly* use `MemberwiseClone` on itself correctly, so nothing is gained by having the method exposed to derived classes.

Answer (score 0):

The next best thing I can offer you (following what Skeet has already explained) is to make it a single step harder to see the property. This isn't great - and not how I would use explicit interfaces, but it's something to know about.

```
 interface I
 {
   int Prop { get; set; }
 }

 class A : I
 {
   int I.Prop { get; set; }
 }

 class B : A
 {
   public void Bar()
   {
     (this as I).Prop = 2;
   }
 }

 class C : B
 {
   public void Foo()
   {
     //Prop = 1;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible to create a container for the variable, and share it between the SubClass and the SuperClass, like this:

```
class Prop {
    public string Str = "a string";
}
class A {
    Prop prop;
    protected A(Prop p) { prop = p; }
    public A() : this(new Prop()) { }
}
class B : A {
    Prop prop;
    private B(Prop p) : base(p) { prop = p; }
    public B() : this(new Prop()) { }
}
class C : B {
    public void Meth() {
        // has no access to prop.Str
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible from day 1 of C# by hiding a member from the base. In particular, you can hide a member with any type of member. I feel the most natural way is to hide the field in this scenario is to hide it with a method.

```cs
public class Base
{
  protected int Foo;
}

public class Derived : Base
{
  // Current class can access base.Foo.
  public Derived() { base.Foo = 1; }
  // Hide base.Foo for further derived classes.
  [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
  [Obsolete("This is used to turn a protected field into private.", true)]
  protected new void Foo() { throw new FieldAccessException(); }
}

public class FurtherDerived : Derived
{
  // In this scope, base.Foo resolves to the method Derived.Foo.
  // If you try calling it, the compiler complains.
  // It is also impossible to say base.base.Foo.
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem.

Comment: @FluffyKitten I think how the code works is explained in the code comments?

Comment: This answer was in the review queue as a "Low Quality Post". It is always preferable to include some explanation in the text also, even if it is just a summary. This makes it easier for other users to see if the answer might be useful to them without having to go through the code :)